# How much change to the question is too much?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits

I answered a Bounty question

[AddHandler not working for .php files - Apache 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342964/addhandler-not-working-for-php-files-apache-2-4/29617609)

The scope of the original question was narrow but, as you can see, [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29342964/3) changed the scope of the question (incorporating my answer in the change). So the question went from (my paraphrase)

> How do I make Apache use my custom handler for PHP?

To

> How do I make my custom handler work alongside the default PHP handler?

The former is just on the boundary of SO topics. The second one is really something for Server Fault (assuming it can be done at all).

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Roll it back to the original version, if your roll-back is rolled back flag it.

Drastically changing a question - especially one with answers - is not something we want to allow. In the first place it invalidates all the work the answerer(s) put into their answer(s) and could, in extremis, result in them getting undeserved down-votes.

It has also been known for users who are question blocked to change their existing questions in order to get round the ban. This is something we want to stop.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306820/is-defacing-own-posts-worth-a-mod-flag/306821#306821