# Correct action if you need to change or clarify a question as a result of an answer

Tags: discussion

I asked, what I *thought* at the time was, a specific well-formed question.

The only answer received on it to date answers the question well as it was asked but it turns out *not for my particular specific scenario*. I now, of course, realise that I ought to have been more specific in my original question but that ship has sailed...

I have upvoted, but not yet accepted the answer.

My options now as I see it, are:

1. Accept the answer then ask a **new** question referencing the original and why it's not suitable for my specific scenario
2. Edit my original question and add enough comments to include the specifics I omitted originally and hope for a revised answer

(2) seems the most 'natural' but it would make the existing answer (which is a good solution and of potential value for at least a proportion of people who could face a similar problem) appear to not answer the question. I am therefore leaning towards (1).

Which is the right approach? (Or am I missing a third option?)

Comment: I'd opt for option "1", since otherwise you'd likely be invalidating a good and appropriate answer.

Comment: [How much change to the question is too much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much)

Comment: I would also opt for option one, but we must be aware, that there might be ppl, voting to close the second one as a dupe of the first one, which I have also seen on stack overflow so far.

Comment: see also: [“What to do when someone answers” - Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/839601)