# How should progressive questions be handled?

Tags: discussion, questions

As I have started participating in SO more and more, a recurrent situation pops up every now and then: progressive questions.

I'm not sure it's the right term to express it, so let me give you an example:

---

**Initial question:** I'm having an issue because of `X`.

**Answer:** The solution to your issue with `X` is `...`.

**OP comments on answer:** Thank you, I fixed my issue with `X` but now I'm having an issue with `Y`.

---

In this short scenario above, the initial question was answered, but due to the solution, the user is facing another issue which may or may not be related to the solution.

Now, my issue with this is that 70-80% of the time, the secondary question can be easily found with a simple Google search.

On one hand, I could either just answer it, or on the other hand, I could tell the user to make a new question about it.

### TL;DR

When a user asks a question after the initial question was answered, am I expected to answer him or ask him to create another question because it's a different problem?

### Update

Relevant example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109802/how-to-fix-request-method-post-not-supported-in-spring-boot/50109873?noredirect=1#comment87237865_50109873)

As you can see, despite having already answered the first question, two more are asked which are *related* to the question, but still easy to answer after a quick search.

### Update 2

I'm not talking about the [question being modified](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much), but more questions being asked *after* the initial question has been resolved.

Comment: The term of art for that is ["chameleon question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: @duplode Now my question feels like a duplicate. Is it? In that post, OP's asking for exit strategy ideas for those type of questions, whereas I'm asking for how it should be handled.

Comment: Possibly, though we can't close MSO questions against MSE ones (and I don't know if there is a corresponding target question here).

Comment: @brasofilo The question is not being changed, rather, more questions are added after the first question has been solved.

Comment: Feel free to ignore new questions in comments.  If the OP doesn't get an answer right away, hopefully they will search on their own.  As long as the OP isn't editing the new questions into the actual SO *question* post, there's no pollution of the real content and you can just leave it alone if you don't want to put more effort in.

Comment: Maybe a subset of a chameleon question? They're extending the scope of  A into ABC...

Comment: I like the (possibly unintentional?) self-demonstration in this question.

Comment: It might be called a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Comment: _"@OP, If you required help with issue Y, please open a new question."_ ... then move on and don't get into a discussion about issue Y.

Comment: This issue is sometimes called a "Russian Doll Question", in reference to matryoshka, the famous Russian nesting dolls. Open one, and there's another waiting to be opened.

Comment: @RobertColumbia you're making it sound _cute_ from that perspective

Comment: @RobertColumbia you're making it sound like opening them is *fun*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should remind the user to ask a separate question about this.

> **OP comments on answer**: Thank you, I fixed my issue with X but now I'm having an issue with Y.
>
> **You answer to OP**: This is an unrelated issue. You might want to ask a separate question about this. Make sure you post your updated code and describe your issue Y in details.

Comments are so easy to add, it often feels natural to keep asking additional questions in comments. People may genuinely forget that there is a dedicated "Ask your question" box. Or maybe they feel that it's inappropriate to ask a different question which has 80% of the code/text identical to the old question (but which is still different). Or, more likely, just too lazy.

Comment: I also offer the user to leave a comment for me on my answer with a link to have a look, if we want to the go with the welcoming vibe that's washing over us.

Answer (score 1):

If the question asker's scenario itself includes both X and Y questions (e.g. code with obvious Bug X and an underlying Bug Y that appears when Bug X is solved, the question is by nature off-topic, unclear, or too broad. In the code debugging situation, close as *off-topic* for being a debugging request with no MCVE (by definition, an MCVE demonstrates *one* issue). If not a debugging request (e.g. "How do I foo the bar in Fortran 90? Thanks, I also want to reticulate this spline, how can I do that? What if the stack overflows? How can I make it run on VMS?"), close as *unclear* or *too broad*, or simply flat-out refuse to extend the question scope. Roll back the OP's attempts to extend the question and tell them to ask a new question. Flag for mod attention if a rollback war ensues.